# How to shift each pixel in an image in some direction by a specified amount

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working with OpenCV - C++. I want to change the color value of each pixel in the image by some user-defined magnitude(0-10) in a user-defined direction (0 - 360 degrees).

A brute-force solution will be to calculate the value of the new colour for each pixel and for each channel.
But I wanted to check if there is simpler way to do this with pre-existing functions in OpenCV ? Or if there is some optimisation available by using matrices?

**EDIT:**
I want to shift the colour of each pixel and NOT the pixel itself.

Comment: you what to change the color or transform/Translate the image to a distance (x,y)?

Comment: I want to change the colour of the pixel or in other words translate the colour in the RGB space

Comment: yourMat += cv::Scalar(tb,tg,tr); not sure whether it is the most efficient way.

Comment: What do you mean by "degree". In RGB, I am not aware of the degree concept of color. It something related to another color space like HSV space. May you explain a bit more?

Comment: By 'degree', I meant to quantify the direction in which I wanted to shift the colour.

Comment: I think you want to convert to HSL colorspace and then apply Micka's addition of a Scalar, just to the Hue channel, to shift the hues around the circle.